# get row data from Nx's tensor variable response error message

Tags: elixir

[enter link description here](https://hexdocs.pm/nx/intro-to-nx.html#nx-and-tensors)

The sample code give the error message as follows:

```
iex(37)> tensor =
...(37)>   1..4
1..4
iex(38)>   |> Enum.chunk_every(2)
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
iex(39)>   |> Nx.tensor(names: [:y, :x])
#Nx.Tensor<
  s64[y: 2][x: 2]
  [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
  ]
>


iex(33)> tensor[x: 1]
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Range.fetch/2 is undefined (Range does not implement the Access behaviour)
    (elixir 1.13.4) Range.fetch(1..4, [x: 1])
    (elixir 1.13.4) lib/access.ex:285: Access.get/3
iex(33)> tensor[y: 0..1]
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Range.fetch/2 is undefined (Range does not implement the Access behaviour)
    (elixir 1.13.4) Range.fetch(1..4, [y: 0..1])
    (elixir 1.13.4) lib/access.ex:285: Access.get/3
```

Comment: Can you try to replace `1..4` by `[1, 2, 3, 4]`? I think it may be some limitation of Nx.

Comment: Thanks. By using `list` [1,2,3,4] the problem has been solved.